# Получение длинных скриптовых объектов в SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

При разработке системы мягкого обновления реляционных баз данных мы столкнулись с такой проблемой.

В файле схемы базы данных мы сохраняем скриптовые объекты как текст их скрипта. Его мы получаем запросом к системному представлению INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES. Для не слишком сложных объектов всё работает нормально. Но если размер скрипта превышает ширину колонки ROUTINE_DEFINITION в INFORMATION_SCHEMA (4000 символов), SQL Server просто обрезает скрипт. Пока что мы считаем, что если длина скрипта ровно 4000 символов, значит скрипт скорее всего обрезан, и прерываем создание файла схемы бросанием исключения.

Но в связи с намечающимися перспективами эту проблему нужно решить. Библиотека Smo каким-то образом разруливает эту ситуацию, но мы отказались от неё по причине крайне низкой производительности и проблем с развёртыванием. Найти в выцепленных Рефлектором исходниках этой библиотеки место, где читаются скрипты, тоже не получилось.

Кроме того, одной из сложностей является то, что для обеспечения желаемой производительности требуется получать все скрипты всех объектов заданного типа одним запросом. Хотя, на худой конец можно считать, что обрезанные скрипты - это единичные случаи, и вариант с повторным запросом только обрезанных скриптов тоже сгодится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
select object_definition( object_id('test_3') )
```

Comment: Получился вот такой запрос.

SELECT ROUTINE_NAME AS Name, object_definition(object_id(ROUTINE_NAME)) AS Definition FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES

Спасибо, работает!